# Pass data to file child.component.ts file not child template

Tags: angular, data-binding, components

I'm passing a value from a parent component to a child component. But before displaying this value in the child.component.html I would like to increase it by 2 ***in the app.component.ts file*** and then display it in child.component.html.

In the example below I take an input value in the parent component, increase it by 2 in app.component.ts. Then I pass it to the child component, where I would like to ***again*** increase the value by 2.

child.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() quantity: number;

  constructor() {

  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  childFunction(){
    this.quantity = this.quantity + 2;
  }

}
```

child.component.html

```
<div class="container" style="border: 3px solid #458075; background-color: #6D948C; border-radius: 15px;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <p>
        Parent value + 4 : {{ quantity }}
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The parent html file app.component.html

```
<div class="container" style="border: 3px solid #515B89; background-color: #79809E; border-radius: 15px;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <h1>
        {{title}}
      </h1>
      <label for="box">Value:</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="value" (ngModelChange)="fun()" />
      <p>value: {{ value }}</p>
      <p>value + 2 : {{ newvalue }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col--xs-12">
      <app-child [quantity]=newvalue></app-child>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';
  value: number = null;
  newvalue: number = null;

  constructor(){
  }

  ngOnInit(){
  }

  fun(){
    this.newvalue = this.value + 2;
  }
}
```

**EDIT:** solution,
So I need to use ngOnChanges() but that means importing it and implementing it on the class in the child component like this,

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
@Input() quantity: number;

  constructor() {

  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  ngOnChanges(){
      this.quantity = this.quantity + 2;
  }
}
```

**Appended:**
There is still some odd behaviour in that the value `newvalue` in the child component displays as 2 before any value is input.

[image]

Ok I solved that particular little problem with,

```
ngOnChanges(){
    if(this.quantity){
      this.quantity = this.quantity + 2;
    }
  }
```

Thanks,

Comment: You are doing it already, whats the problem?

Comment: Besides the missing quotes here: `[quantity]=newvalue`, what *is* the problem?

Comment: I am? I'm not calling childFunction() anywhere. Where would I call this so that it will always be updated if the quantity value changed? Thanks for looking at this.

Comment: @R.Richards should there be quotes on the 'quantity' or 'newvalue'? The value for quantity is displaying in the child.component.html Thanks

Comment: correct syntax: [quantity]="newvalue"

Comment: Think about adding a [`OnChanges`](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges) lifecycle hook in the child component. The quotes *should* be around 'newvalue' (but if it works, meh).

Comment: Great that is working. I'll edit the question, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a [`OnChanges`](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges) lifecycle hook in the child component should give you the functionality that you seek.

What this will do is allow you to run your incrementing function when the `@Input()` variable value changes.

Any `@Input()` variable value that changes will fire the `ngOnChanges` you add as a part of implementing `OnChanges`.

Comment: Thanks Richard that's going to be very useful. Thanks for the clear explanation too.